# Applied migration entry not presente on schema_migrations table

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, migration, schema-migration

I got an app running in production on heroku, but there is a problem with the schema_migrations table.

The last migration changes are present at the `db/schema.rb` file, but there is no entry for this migration in the `schema_migrations` table.

So when running `rake db:version` I got the number corresponding to the migration executed before this last migration.

I believe i should add an entry for this migration on `schema_migrations` table, but i am not sure of how to do this without affecting the date on my database, and remotely on heroku.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had a similar problem, where I had no migrations in my schema_migrations table. So I had to run this:

```
Dir.open('db/migrate').each do |fname|
    i = fname.split('_').first.to_i
    next if i == 0
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("INSERT INTO schema_migrations (version) VALUES(#{i})")
end
```

[source](http://selfsolved.com/problems/resetting-rails-schema_migration)